# Can syslog pri value can be negative?

Tags: haproxy, syslog, syslog-ng

First i will tell you my architecture
client--->haproxy--->syslog-ng--->kafka
the client is Cisco ASA and haproxy is server for load-balancing and syslog-ng is for receiving ,filtering and sending logs to kafka(destination)
The client sends logs to haproxy and haproxy send logs to syslog-ng using tcp transport
As in tcp the client-server timeout breaks whenever client restored the connection its PRI value is negative which we seeing in wireshark.With this issue the messages gets mixup
Connection restored is normal but PRI value is negative this is incorrect.

I am showing you the the logs

```
 <-1>May 24 2021 17:40:28: %ASA--1-6414004: TCP Syslog Server private:xx.xx.xx.xx/1470 - 
Connection restored\\nCAL\\\\John Mike/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) to private:xx.xx.xx.xx/xx duration 0:00:00 bytes 142 
(John Mike/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)\\nxxxxxxx)\\n4 2021 17:40:28: %ASA-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 1733810491
```

we've increase the client connection timeout from 1min to 12 hr but the problem is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Some version of the Cisco ASA TCP Syslog code are affected by [bug CSCvz85683](https://bst.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCvz85683):

> **Symptom:**
>
> Wrong syslog message format, ex for 414004:
>
> ```
> -1>Sep 08 2021 10:46:25: %ASA--1-6414004: TCP Syslog Server private:xx.xx.xx.xx/1470 - Connection restored\n (xx.xx.xx.xx/64437)
> ```
>
> **Conditions:**
>
> External logging to TCP server is enabled
>
> **Workaround:**
> NA
>
> **Further Problem Description:**

ASA syslog messages have 6-digit ID

> The valid range for message IDs is between 100000 and 999999.

Source: [Cisco ASA Series Syslog Messages. About ASA Syslog Messages.](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/syslog/b_syslog/about.html#con_4768518)

When logging via TCP on versions with the defect code, will shift the priority (`6` in this case) into the message code (`414004` in this case) and use an illegal priority `-1`.

According to the bug, this has been fixed in version 9.14.4.